# overflow 99788px on right

Tags: ios, flutter

My code:

````
```flutter
Widget _buildActionForTask(TaskInfo task) {
if (task.status == DownloadTaskStatus.undefined) {
  return new RawMaterialButton(
    onPressed: () {
      _requestDownload(task); /*download button*/
    },
    child: new Icon(
      Icons.file_download,
      size: 30,
    ),
    shape: new CircleBorder(),
    constraints: new BoxConstraints(minHeight: 32.0, minWidth: 32.0),
  );
} else if (task.status == DownloadTaskStatus.running) {
  /*there is my stuck*/
   return new RawMaterialButton(
    onPressed: () {
      _pauseDownload(task); /*pause button*/
    },
    child: new Icon(
      Icons.pause,
      size: 30,
      color: Colors.white,
    ),
    shape: new CircleBorder(),
    constraints: new BoxConstraints(minHeight: 32.0, minWidth: 32.0),
  );
} else if (task.status == DownloadTaskStatus.paused) {
  return new RawMaterialButton(
    onPressed: () {
      _resumeDownload(task); /*resume button*/
    },
    child: new Icon(
      Icons.play_arrow,
      size: 30,
      color: Colors.green,
    ),
    shape: new CircleBorder(),
    constraints: new BoxConstraints(minHeight: 32.0, minWidth: 32.0),
  );
}
````

Here is my appbar:

```
appBar: AppBar(
      title: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text("Image ${this.widget.index}"),
          Builder(
            builder: (context) => _isLoading
                ? Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  )
                : _permissionReady
                    ? _buildActionForTask(taskInfo)
                    : FlatButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          _checkPermission().then((hasGranted) {
                            setState(() {
                              _permissionReady = hasGranted;
                            });
                          });
                        },
                        child: Text(
                          "Thử lại",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 20.0),
                        )),
          )
        ],
      ),
      flexibleSpace: GradientBar(),
    ),
```

I am creating a function to download. After I hit the download button, it encountered this error. Download and delete buttons are displayed normally.
I tried many ways but still got that error. I still don't know how it can overflow `99788px`?

[image: Error log]

[image: Error on Ios]

Comment: Please share your code with question

Comment: Can you remove the `Builder`..not sure if it works..but just give it a try..!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a Row inside title, try using just the text widget and move the other widgets (, the one inside builder) to the action parameter, it accepts a list of widgets to the right of the appbar

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your button with a `Container` and giving it fixed width.
You can also try to give fixed width to your `constraints`

Comment: Try with @EdwynZN 's answer. Change your title row by an action parameter that takes a list of widgets.